# Re-clone a Oracle Virtualbox machine but to keep Windows 7 license?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, license, clone

My linked-clone machine is down for now and I need to re-clone it from the original machine.

The problem is that I have use a Windows 7 license key on this machine, ie. if I delete it and clone the new one, the license is gone; to keep the license remain I may need to clone the hard disk only.

So my question is how to re-clone a machine and transfer the key?

Comment: Keep in mind you can reactivate Windows licenses.  If it doesn't work automatically, you can call to reactivate. I've done it - it works

Comment: @uSlackr My problem is the license is once activated I'm afraid.

Comment: Yes, but they will likely allow you to re-activate it.

Comment: Is the problem that you don't know the product key?

Comment: @Paul No it is not. I know the product key.

Comment: @uSlackr So it is okie to re-activate on a new machine? So how does that mean a Windows 7 license key can be reused many times if the owner share/reshell it?

Comment: No, you cannot use it on two machines.  But , if you rebuild one, MS will usually reactivate it when it is rebuilt.

Comment: @uSlackr Thanks. I guess I got to `clonezilla` the machine for license safety. I cannot re-create the machine for now.